# How long does a Diablo 3 Season last?

Tags: diablo-iii

We know what happens to your characters, EXP, items, gold, etc. at the end of the Season in the new Diablo 3 mechanic. However I've not been able to locate a good source stating how long we'll have for the season.

**How long does a Diablo 3 Season last?**

Comment: Unfortunately, we won't know this until the first one ends.

Comment: @Frank has the information not been provided anywhere? I thought I might have just been failing to find it.

Comment: To my knowledge, Bliz has said that they're going to be experimenting with the length of seasons.  But I'm not sure if they've said how long that's going to be.

Comment: Frank is correct. At this point there is no word on the duration of the season. It is stated that they will be for a "limited duration", that it will be between 1 to 6 months, and I heard (although not even from an unofficial source so take this with a grain of salt) that it could be when all of the conquest boards have 1000 users on them.

Comment: When it came to Starcraft 2, the first few seasons were all different length as Blizzard experimented, until they ultimately settled on a more stable duration.

Answer (score 1):

From [a green post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/14058715775) on the forum:

> Season duration will be a “few months”

Answer (score -3):

The diablo wiki says they are thinking around 3 months.

Comment: Please expand on you answer and leave sources for any quotes

Comment: Given the number of people who have commented that Blizzard haven't announced this, I would like to see better sourcing than "this wiki says". Does the wiki give a source for this figure?